# automatically rendering/putting email and passwords whenever page reloads in JSX

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

While writing autocomplete in text field of email and password in login page, it is rendering or automatically putting email and passwords whenever page reloads

I haven't added functionality yet in login page. Only JSX part has been done now. I have uploaded whole code of login page in this screenshot.

[image: login page, issue in text field of email and password]

[image: login page mui]

[image: context to login page in navbar]

Comment: Please add code as code blocks not screencaptures

Comment: I haven't added functionality yet in login page. Only JSX part has been done now. I have uploaded whole code of login that screenshot.

Comment: This is a browser default behaviour, if you want to disable such autofilling add `autocomplete="off"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blue tint in the textfields suggests that your email and password have been saved to your browser and the browser is autofilling the email and password.

Try removing these credentials from your browser